# Flex Carousel that adjusts in size

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

I'm trying to make a carousel that adjusts in size like my other flex elements so the format of my website is the same no matter the size of the browser window. But I've tried wrapping the carousel in a flex div. And googling a potential fix for this but I haven't been able to find anything. This is my code its nothing but just the carousel code. Another problem I have come across is that when the carousel adjusts in size the elements (such as the next/prev buttons on the side of the picture or the indicators at the bottom)  within the carousel will not adjust in size and or position and will but completely out of place.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block" src="pic1.jpg" alt="Missing Picture 1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block" src="pic2.jpg" alt="Missing Picture 2">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block" src="pic3.jpg" alt="Missing Picture 3">
    </div>
  </div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: so basically you are looking for the responsive carousel. is that right?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Yes I tried to use the owl carousel but it seems to glitch out when i try to apply a flex positional property to it.